# How to republish youtube video with different id?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to republish a video with a different video id via API.

I can upload the same video, which will give a different id.  However, I want to skip the process of uploading and take an already existing video and change the video id? Is this possible?

Also Is it possible to duplicate a youtube video with api?

Comment: Such a function would be abused immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to republish a video with a different video id via API.

You understand YouTube frowns upon duplicate videos right?

> I can upload the same video, which will give a different id.

If you upload the same video again it will get a new id as it will be a different video

> However, I want to skip the process of uploading and take an already existing video and change the video id? Is this possible?

No you will need to upload the video again

> Also Is it possible to duplicate a youtube video with api?

Yes you could upload it using the YouTube api but until your application is verified videos uploaded with the YouTube api will be private.  SO you will need to go though the application verification process.